# How is the keyboard connected in Dell Latitude E7440?

Tags: laptop, keyboard, dell-latitude, connector

I’d like to learn which cable is used for sending keypresses to the notebook, since the following documentation, combined with knowledge about older models, makes it unclear.

From the [“Removing the Keyboard” section of the “Dell Latitude E7440 Owner’s Manual”](https://www.dell.com/support/manuals/pl/pl/plbsd1/latitude-e7440-ultrabook/late7440om-v3/removing-the-keyboard):

> Perform the following steps as shown in the illustration:
>
> 1. Lift the keyboard-backlight cable latch [1].
> 2. Remove the cable from the system board [2].
> 3. Lift the trackstick cable latch [3].
> 4. Remove the cable from the system board [4].
> 5. Lift the *keyboard cable* latch [5].
> 6. Remove the cable from the system board [6].
> 7. Lift the touchpad cable latch [7].
> 8. Remove the cable from the system board [8].
>
> [image: An illustration for the above points]

(Emphasis mine.) There you can see that the *keyboard cable* (I guess that’s the one to send key events with) is disconnected in steps 5–6 which correspond to numbers 5 and 6 on the illustration. But on that illustration, there’s a cable identified by steps 3–4 that much better resembles the cables that were used to send key events in older Latitude notebooks. Which one is right?

Answer (score 0):

steps 3–4
The cable you refer to in English is called Flat Ribbon cable (or Multi-wire planar). It is a flat cable with several connectors and is not usually repaired, because it is quite hard and is usually integrated into the keyboard itself. Most likely you have to replace the keyboard if the cable is broken

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I don’t own such keyboard, so fortunately there’s nothing to repair. I asked the above question in order to learn which of 3–4 and 5–6 cables is used for transmitting key presses (not trackpoint movements, not touchpad events and not backlight power; I assume there’s a separate cable for each of these purposes). The docs say that 3–4 is used by the trackpoint and that 5–6 by the keyboard, but am not that sure, as for example D630’s cables and connectors suggest it’s arranged the other way around. As said, I cannot test it, since I don’t currently have such keyboard.